# Replacing \ with \\

Tags: c#, replace

I have a string. I want to search for a single slash and then replace "\" (single slash) with a "\" (double slash).

```
string Method1(string s) 
{
     string upadtedString = s;
     if (s.Contains("\\"))
     {
      //do nothing
     }
     else if(s.Contains("\"))
     {
          string s1 = "\";
          string s2 = "\\";
          upadtedString.Replace(s1,s2);
          s = upadtedString;
     }
     return s;
 }
```

`

Comment: thanks all, is it ok to use string or should use string builder ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape backslashes or use a verbatim string literal, and also understand that strings are immutable - `Replace` doesn't change the *existing* string, it returns a *new* string:

```
// Escaping with an extra backslash
updatedString = s.Replace("\\", "\\\\");

// Using a verbatim string literal
updatedString = s.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

For more information on escaping and verbatim string literals, see my [strings article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx).

Comment: Hi, could you please suggest a best way to handle escape chars. There is another post by me

Comment: @starz: That depends on what you mean by "handle". You need to be a lot clearer in your questions.

Comment: I mean i get input strings which might contain \0, \, \\, \t, \a etc. These are input i get from another application.SO when i get such string , My application serializes and then deserializes the string. COnsidering a case of "\0 Mesg" input i get exception while deserailzation. So I want to modify the strin to "\\0Mesg" and then perform a serialization so tht i can avoid a exception while deserialzation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `@` character in front of your string literals to ensure that they're taken as *verbatim* strings and your slashes not interpreted as escape characters.  You can also "escape" the `\` character but using an additional `\`.

For example:

```
string s1 = @"\";
string s2 = @"\\";
string s3 = updatedString.Replace(s1,s2);
```

or

```
string s1 = "\\";
string s2 = "\\\\";
string s3 = updatedString.Replace(s1,s2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either escape your backslashes, or use string literals, so try:

```
string Method1(string s) 
{
    return s.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
}
```

or

```
string Method1(string s) 
{
    return s.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
}
```

There are also other problems with your code - you can initialise variables when you declare them:

```
string upadtedString = s;
```

The `Replace` method will not change anything if there are no `\` to be found, therefore there is no need for `if (s.Contains("\"))`.

Strings are immutable (Do not change) so you need to use `string replaced = original.Replace(...);` rather than expecting `orginal.Replace(...)` to change `original` in place.

You can declare strings directly into the method call rather than using `s1` and `s2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string Method1(string s) 
{
    return s.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
}
```