# JavaScript replace single slash to double slash?

Tags: javascript, string, ionic-framework, ionic3, str-replace

I currently have the following string with me

```
var docPath="\\\\Server\Users\Files\Order\file1.pdf"
```

Where in I need to replace the single backslashes to two back slashes in my ionic 3 mobile application

like this  `var docPath="\\\\Server\\Users\\Files\\Order\\file1.pdf"`

This is what Ive tried so far

```
docPath=docPath.replace('\\', "\\\\")
```

which doesn't change anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace single backslash "\" with double backslashes "\\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144090/replace-single-backslash-with-double-backslashes)

Answer (score 1):

The slash character is interpreted as the start of an escape sequence when the JavaScript parser **parses the JavaScript source code**.

By the time you try to apply your replace call to the string, the slashes have already been converted into what their escape sequences represent.

**You are too late!**

---

You have to fix *the source code*. You can't recover the data after the JavaScript parser has destroyed it.

```
var docPath="\\\\Server\\Users\\Files\\Order\\file1.pdf"
```

Comment: So what needs to be fixed in the source code in this case ?

Comment: @Codebadger — I refer you to the last line of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is already at

```
var docPath="\\\\Server\Users\Files\Order\file1.pdf".
```

I think

```
var docPath="\\\\Server\\Users\\Files\\Order\\file1.pdf"
```

would be correct